# Nestjs repository pattern config challenge

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to figure out how the "Repository Pattern" of TypeOrm in Nest works. I would like to have a `resources` file in which a `local` and a remote file hold the different entites, controllers, modules etc. See screenshot

[image]

When the app is building I`m getting the following error:

```
[Nest] 3186   - 11/19/2018, 10:44:43 PM   [ExceptionHandler] No repository for "Project" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection? +1ms
```

From the [Nest](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database) and TypeORM documentation I can triangulate, that I have to tell the application where it can find the entities or at least this is what I believe the error is trying to tell me.

I'm using a `.env` to pull the config for TypeORM in:

```
TYPEORM_CONNECTION = postgres
TYPEORM_HOST = localhost
TYPEORM_USERNAME = xyz
TYPEORM_PASSWORD = xyz
TYPEORM_DATABASE = xyz
TYPEORM_PORT = 5432
TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE = true
TYPEORM_LOGGING = true
TYPEORM_ENTITIES = src/server/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AngularUniversalModule } from './modules/angular-universal/angular-universal.module';
import { JiraService } from './services/jira.service'
// modules
import { ProjectModule } from './resources/local/project/project.module'
// sync
import {ProjectsSync} from './sync/projects.sync'

@Module({
  imports: [
    ProjectModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
    AngularUniversalModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers:[JiraService, ProjectsSync],
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

project.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ProjectService } from './project.service';
import { ProjectController } from './project.controller';
import { Project } from './project.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Project])],
  providers: [ProjectService],
  controllers: [ProjectController],
})
export class ProjectModule {}
```

project.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Project } from './project.entity';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Project)
    private readonly projectRepository: Repository<Project>,
  ) {}

  async findAll(): Promise<Project[]> {
    return await this.projectRepository.find();
  }
}
```

project.entity.ts

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Project {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ length: 500 })
  name: string;
}
```

project.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ProjectService } from './project.service';
import { Project } from './project.entity';

@Controller('project')
export class ProjectController {
  constructor(private readonly projectService: ProjectService) {}

  @Get()
  findAll(): Promise<Project[]> {
    return this.projectService.findAll();
  }
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to run correctly with node (not ts-node) as you need to parse entities within `dist` and not `src`. Personally I prefer using a factory method to instanciate the TypeOrm connection so I can change this path depending on env (and parsing other props from env files within code).

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess, have you tried:

```
TYPEORM_ENTITIES = ./server/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}
```

And/or switching the imports in app.module.ts putting the TypeOrmModule first:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
    ProjectModule,
    AngularUniversalModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers:[JiraService, ProjectsSync],
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .env file change

`TYPEORM_ENTITIES = src/server/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}`

to

`TYPEORM_ENTITIES = /../**/*.entity.{js,ts}`

in your app.module use:

```
const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
    type: process.env.TYPEORM_CONNECTION,
    host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
    port: process.env.TYPEORM_PORT,
    username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
    synchronize: process.env.TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE,
    logging: process.env.TYPEORM_LOGGING,
    entities: [__dirname + process.env.TYPEORM_ENTITIES]
}

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(typeOrmConfig),
    ProjectModule,
    AngularUniversalModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers:[JiraService, ProjectsSync],
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```